# How to avoid overlapping between two divs positioning absolute inside a div positioning relative?

Tags: css, html, absolute, overlap

The following code works if the page has enough space to host all divs, but if I resize at minimum the page the two divs positioning absolute overlap. How can I avoid that?

```css
#div-chatroom {
  position: relative;
  height: calc(100% - 70px);
  /* IE9+ and future browsers */
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 70px);
  /* Firefox */
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 70px);
  /* Chrome, Safari */
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  border-right: 2px solid #333333;
  overflow: auto;
}

#div-messages {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 110px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  min-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#div-sending {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-chatroom">
  <div id="div-messages">messages here</div>
  <div id="div-sending">sending tools here</div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE #1**
As required the code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f_ficarola/3rDx8/18/) (but if the two divs have `position: absolute` it doesn't seem to work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got an equivalent result by changing approach.

CSS ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f_ficarola/Tac3W/21/)):

```
#div-chatroom {
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 70px); /* IE9+ and future browsers */
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 70px); /* Firefox */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 70px); /* Chrome, Safari */
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    border-right: 2px solid #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    overflow: auto;
}

#div-messages {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    min-height: 200px;
    height: calc(100% - 100px); /* IE9+ and future browsers */
    height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px); /* Firefox */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px); /* Chrome, Safari */
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
}

#div-sending {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the whole purpose of position:absolute is for element to not be dependend or any other elemends on the page (except for it's parent) co you can't actually achieve this. if you want to aligh them accordingly, you can do this using position style other than absolute. post your code to jsfiddle, then we will be able to provide good solution.